# Print statements python degrading performance

Tags: python, python-2.7

How much python print statements impact the code performance?

I have 2.8M records to process, when i ran it with prints (log like --> Execution Success for "ID") on screen it was running too slow. when i piped '>' the script and ran it was showing performance boost.

my questions are -

1. if print on screen impacts the code performance?
2. let's suppose, one case is, i have logged-in to the screen where i am running the program and monitoring all the prints and other case i am logged off of the server but it would be still printing to terminal. will there be any performance difference in these two cases?
3. why i am seeing a performance increase when i piped ">" the prints into a file?

What is happening in the background?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it does impact performance. And it's not just the printing; your terminal also has to scroll the text etc., thus writing to file can be faster. But is printing 2.8M records really useful in the first place?

Comment: However, 420k records in 20h means ~171ms per record. In this case, `print` should be a rather minor factor.

Comment: Unless your records are huge and you're fully printing them to STDOUT (or printing them involves a lot of pre-processing) I'd look elsewhere for performance boost.

Comment: @zwer i am not printing the records, i am just printing the confirmation like "INFO : Execution successful for 'ID'". i want to understand the impact of print statements. thanks

Comment: If you are doing this in a remote session, there might be additional overhead in transferring the printed output to your computer, but again, this should amount only to a fraction of those 170ms.

Comment: @tobias_k , you are absolutely right. i should write it to a file but i want to understand the impact of print statements.

Comment: You should profile your code and determine where the bottlenecks are (and what would speed it up the most). Otherwise what you're doing is little more guessing.